# Can't print cyrillics cahracters in terminal

Tags: c++, ubuntu, terminal, utf-8, ascii

I have an labaratoly work from my university - I have to print ASCII table with ukrainian symbols, then make transliteration from ukrainian to english but I have met problems.

So, I am to print `ASCII` extended table in `C++`, it must include Ukrainian letters (cyrilics).
I am on `KDE neon 5.26` linux distribution, it is based on `Ubuntu`. Terminal is KDE's `Console` obiviously.

I made that code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(void) {

        for (unsigned char i = 32; int(i) < 255; i++) {
                std::cout <<" [" << i << "] " << int(i) << " \t";
                if ((i-1)%5 == 0)
                        std::cout << "\n";
        }

        char ua_str[] = "Привіт";  // hello in ukrainian
        std::cout << "\n\n" << ua_str << "\n" << ua_str[4] << " is " << int(ua_str[4]) << "\n";

        return std::cout.fail() ? EXIT_FAILURE : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled it with `g++ lab3.cpp`. It produces such output:

I am interested, how it printed `char ua_str[]` but won't print `ua_str[4]`.

Terminal encoding is set to `UTF8`, I cannot find `ASCII` in Terminal encoding settings. If I redirect output to `abc.txt` text file with `./a.out > abc.txt` and open it, it looks like the next:

So, I ran `locale -a` in terminal:

Then I ried to add `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "uk_UA.utf8");` to my program in `int main(void)` before the `for` loop but It didn't changed anything, output is the same...

I am to make transliteration script later but can't print and work properly with ukrainian letters...

So, question is: How to print and work with cyrillic cahrs in `C++` on `KDE neon 5.26`?

I think than I have tried everething I could and it wont work. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rtf for Ukrainian Character Set KOI8-U :  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2319.html .... You can map your std ascii table to the required cyrillic characters. Another option is to look at something like yandex. https://yandex.com/dev/translate/ it is an api for translating but I think its a service that charges but there is usage limits or just a temporary key if not paid for. It's pretty useful for translating and an easy api.

Comment: How I can perform the first option?

Comment: Oh, forget about my last comment! I found `KOI8-U` in my terminal settings and after that my program prodused desired output! Tnank you a lot!

Comment: @VladyslavRehan: but if you are still programming your program, do it future proof: print results in UTF-8 (so you may need to transcode some inputs, or change logic. But people using your program in future will come to the same error (because everybody now expect UTF-8).